# Unable to Configure Private Git Server with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, config

I have created a Jenkins server on ec2 and on another ec2 instance i have set up a local git server. I am able to connect via ssh from Jenkins to local git server and vice versa. I am trying to create a pipeline in jenkins which should use local git server repository rather than my repository on github.com.

While making this configuration i am getting following error as soon as i paste local git url

"Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -- ssh://ec2-user@15.207.20.40:/home/ec2-user/git/projectname.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

What am i doing wrong or is there any additional configuration required to make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you include a key on your jenkins user and on the Git server (on the EC2)?

1. logging on the Jenkins machine with your Jenkins user
2. Create key for this user
3. Add Jenkins as colaborator on the Git private repository
4. Add key on the personal setting of the colaborator
5. Check the Security Groups of the Jenkins EC2 to see the private Git (this looks fine on your issue)

More info: https://medium.com/facademy/setup-jenkins-for-private-repository-9060f54eeac9

Comment: Thanks, i am not trying to add a private repository from github but rather trying to use github server that i setup on the second ec2 instance. I am new to this so not sure if this is even achievable. My Plan is to set up a CI/CD Docker pipeline. I Could set up CI pipeline with github account and docker registry. now i want to use a local docker registry and local git server for the CI.